# Global section of pullback of an ideal sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

For a local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$ and residue field $\kappa$, and a flat morphism $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec} R$ of schemes,  we consider the short exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} R}$-modules (I omitted the tildes in the sequel)
$$0\rightarrow \mathfrak{m}\rightarrow R\rightarrow\kappa\rightarrow0, $$
whose pullback on $X$ is the short exact sequence (left exactness holds since $X$ is $R$-flat)
$$0\rightarrow f^{\ast}\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X_{\kappa}}\rightarrow 0.$$
Then taking global sections on an open subset $U\subset X$ yields an injection
$$\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)/\Gamma(U,f^{\ast}\mathfrak{m})\hookrightarrow\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_{X_{\kappa}}).$$
**My question** is, do we have $\Gamma(U,f^{\ast}\mathfrak{m})\simeq \Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes_{R}\mathfrak{m}$? In fact, it is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4078955/global-sections-and-fiber-products-x-times-s-operatornamespec-k).
Of course, when $U$ is affine then it is true, but I want to know the general case.

Note that $f^{\ast}\mathfrak{m}$ is a tensor product $f^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\otimes_{f^{-1}R}\mathcal{O}_X$, and taking global sections and tensor products are not compatible in general, so I wonder if in such special case we do have a compatibility.

N.B. The local ring $R$ is not assumed to be Noetherian so $\mathfrak{m}$ is not necessarily finitely generated.

Comment: You are asking whether the projection formula holds in this situation. It will hold if $\frak m$ is finite locally free, so eg if $R$ is a discrete valuation ring. Otherwise, I don't see why this should be true.